# BeginExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteNonQuery handled by CLR

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

why begin execute Non query is used? how both these lines are handled by CLR?

```
SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: `BeginSomeMethodName`/`EndSomeMethodName` are part of the [Asynchronous Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) and in combination do the same as the synchronous method.

Comment: Fyi, the CLR doesn't have much to do with this - those are both just methods on SqlCommand, probably written in C#, and are executed just the same as any other C# / .Net code. CLR is the execution environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods are part of the Asynchronous Programming Model

These link will be useful:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery block's  the program till the query get processed and returns result and coming to BeginExecuteNonQuery will run in asynchronous mode.

Answer (score 0):

SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery();::Initiates the asynchronous execution of the Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure that is described by this SqlCommand.

SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();:: Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

Hope it helps !